# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMI.IRMICustomerService en una conexión RMI

Tags: java, java-8, rmi

Estoy programando una aplicacion RMI y me sale el siguiente error al querer conectar mi cliente con el servidor :

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMI.IRMICustomerService (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

A continuación incluyo mi código.

Mi interfaz : IRMICustomerService.java

```
package RMI;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Date;

  public interface IRMICustomerService extends Remote {

  public void createCustomer(Customer input) throws RemoteException;
public Customer getCustomer(int customerID) throws RemoteException;

 }
```

Mi implementacion : RMICustomerService.java

```
package RMI;

 import java.rmi.RemoteException;
 import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class RMICustomerService extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRMICustomerService  {

  ArrayList<Customer> customerContainer = new ArrayList<Customer>();

  protected RMICustomerService() throws RemoteException {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Customer a = new Customer(1,"Jonathan","xxx");
    Customer b = new Customer(2,"xxx","eeeee");

    customerContainer.add(a);
    customerContainer.add(b);


    }

    @Override
   public void createCustomer(Customer input) throws RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    customerContainer.add(input);
    System.out.println("ok");

    }

    @Override
    public Customer getCustomer(int customerID) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return customerContainer.get(customerID);
   }

   }
```

Para la conexion : StartAndBindRegistry.java

```
   package RMI;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
   import java.rmi.Naming;
 import java.rmi.RemoteException;
       import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

     public class StartAndBindRegistry {

public static void main(String[] Args) throws MalformedURLException, AlreadyBoundException {

    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        String name="//localhost/RMICustomer";
        RMICustomerService rmi = new RMICustomerService();
        Naming.bind(name, rmi);
        System.out.println("Service started");

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Could not start registry");

    }

       }

         }
```

Mi cliente que se conecta : RMIAccountClient.java

```
package Client;

 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
   import java.rmi.Naming;
   import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
  import java.rmi.RemoteException;
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RMIAccountClient {

    public Customer newCustomer() {

    Customer tmp = new Customer();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please introduce the ID of the new customer:");
    tmp.setId_customer(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.println(tmp.getId_customer());

    System.out.println("Please introduce the name of the new customer:");
    tmp.setName(sc.next());
    System.out.println(tmp.getName());

    System.out.println("Please introduce the last name of the new customer:");
    tmp.setVorname(sc.next());
    System.out.println(tmp.getVorname());

    sc.close();


        return tmp;
        }

         public static void main(String[] args) {

    RMIAccountClient obj = new RMIAccountClient();
    String name="//localhost/RMICustomer";
    Customer x = new Customer(2,"kkk","ffff");


    try {
        IRMICustomerService remoteService =(IRMICustomerService)Naming.lookup(name);
        System.out.println(remoteService.getCustomer(1));

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
         }



         }


       }
```

Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: La verdad nose donde esta el error :/

Comment: qué versión de Java usas?

Comment: JavaSE-1.8 porque ?

Answer (score 0):

El problema seguramente es debido a que ya tienes un registro ejecutandose o que no puedes llamar a la direcciòn:

```
String name="//localhost/RMICustomer"
```

de hecho si imprimes el error en este punto seguramente serà un `BindException` :

```
try {
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
    String name="//localhost/RMICustomer";
    RMICustomerService rmi = new RMICustomerService();
    Naming.bind(name, rmi);
    System.out.println("Service started");

} catch (RemoteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Could not start registry: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: El servidor iniicia correctamente, no sale error, pero cuando intento iniciar mi cliente (RMIAccountClient.java), me sale el error que describi arriba y el servidor sigue iniciado, asi que yo imagino que algo esta mal en el cliente pero nose que es. La verdad nose que esta mal .